# How to store camera captured image in SQLite Database in my application?

Tags: android, sqlite

In my application i want to capture the image from secondary camera and store that photos into my SQLite data base not in SD card.Please any one help me how to do that with some sample source code

Comment: If SD card matters, save it in device storage.

Answer (score 3):

How do you think a database system called SQLite, emphasis on the **Lite**, would handle 50 pictures at 2.5mb a piece? That's a 125Mb database, not including the other data. Most of my full blown MS SQL databases that back websites haven't reached that size yet. It would be in your best interest to store on the SD card :).

If this still does not deter you, then look at the [blob](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) datatype in SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can save camera captured image into SQLitedatabase in this way.. 

public class CamActivity extends Activity {



    byte[] byteArray;
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
    protected static final int TAKE_PHOTO_CODE = 0;
    public ImageView imageView;
    private DBAdapter db;
    byte [] imgbyte;
    EditText txtView ;
    String name;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        db=new DBAdapter(CamActivity.this);
        db.open();
        this.imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);          
      txtView=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        Button B = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.camera); 
        B.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
               // cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,getImageUri());
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,CAMERA_REQUEST ); 
            }
        }); 

        Button save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.saving);
        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {            
            public void onClick(View v) {




                name=txtView.getText().toString();


                try
                {

db.insertImageDetails(byteArray,name);  

                }              

                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                 //mySQLiteAdapter.close();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "processing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "image saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }});

        Button G = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.get);
        G.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {           
            public void onClick(View v)

            {

                Intent intent= new Intent(CamActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

    }
            });
        }


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  

        //final byte[] byteArray;
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {  
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");   
           //imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);    
           ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
           photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
             byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
           System.out.println(byteArray);
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), byteArray.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }



        }
```